# How to resolve conflicting distributions in apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, plex

When doing an apt-get update/upgrade I see that error

```
W: Conflicting distribution: https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease (expected public but got )
```

I was upgrading to Ubuntu Zesty 17.04 before and do not know how to fix the above. Already have seen https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/162337/plex-media-server-ppa-for-ubuntu/p4? but there are no suggested fixes for that.

Maybe one of you can give some hints? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should probably go to askubuntu.com because it's not about programming.

Comment: Is it not possible to just move this question to the other forum?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/913211/how-to-resolve-conflicting-distributions-in-apt-get ... cross posted

Answer (score 17):

Edit

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
```

And replace

```
deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main
```

with

```
deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ ./public main
```

...that worked for me.

Comment: I don't have this file : plexmediaserver.list !!

Comment: @McLan – It's whichever file contains the relevant `deb` line(s). You might have them all in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or you might have them in `*.list` files within the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, which lets packages maintain their own repository configurations without messing with others.

Answer (score 3):

I am hit by this warning log and found out this might be caused by a wrong `InRelease` file.

I am making a self managed repo and initial creates `InRelease` file by

```
# apt-ftparchive release ./ > Release
# gpg -abs --default-key xxx -o Release.gpg Release
# gpg --clearsign --default-key xxx -o InRelease Release
```

but this turns out does not add proper metadata, to solve it, I add a new config file and add following contents

```
APT::FTPArchive::Release {
  Origin "test";
  Label "focal-updates";
  Suite "focal-updates";
  Codename "focal";
  Architectures "amd64 i386 source";
  Components "main";
  Description "focal-updates";
};
```

```
# apt-ftparchive release -c=./patch.conf ./ > Release
# gpg -abs --default-key xxx -o Release.gpg Release
# gpg --clearsign --default-key xxx -o InRelease Release
```

then `apt update` is fine and warning message is gone

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case, all I needed to add was the Codename field, which I did with this: `apt-ftparchive release -o APT::FTPArchive::Release::Codename=focal . > Release`

Answer (score 2):

https://forums.plex.tv/t/w-conflicting-distribution-https-downloads-plex-tv-repo-deb-public-inrelease-expected-public/194055/16

This is because they are redoing the packaging:

> public main is correct.
>   You’re not doing anything wrong.
>   What you see is because of how the repository is…
>   As I’ve stated already today, I am working as hard and as fast as I humanly can.
>   The repository will be completely overhauled by the time we complete the new build system (CI) for all of PMS.
>   [[...]](https://forums.plex.tv/t/w-conflicting-distribution-https-downloads-plex-tv-repo-deb-public-inrelease-expected-public/194055/14)

Run the following code and it will update/upgrade Plex.

```
echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list

curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```